# Find new commit ids on a git tag

Tags: git

During each release, I'm checking out to the previous tag, cherry-picking new commit IDs into it and creating a new tag and making a release. For example, if my previous release name is Tag.1.15.50.31. Here is what I'll do,

```
git checkout Tag.1.15.50.31
git cherry-pick new-commit-id-1
git cherry-pick new-commit-id-2
.
.
.
.
so on.
```

And then to create tag, I'll use

```
git tag -a Tag.1.15.50.32 -m 'drop 1.15.50.32'
```

After Tag.1.15.50.32 I did some 4 releases and currently I'm on the tag number Tag.1.15.50.36. Now, how to find newly cherry-picked commit-ids in 32 (i.e., new-commit-id-1 and new-commit-id-2)?

Answer (score 1):

So, you mean you have a commit graph that goes something like this:

```
                 - o - o      <-- various
o - o - o - ... - o - o - o   <-- branches
     \            - o - o     <-- not especially interesting
      \
       o   <-- Tag.1.15.50.30
        \
         o - o - o   <-- Tag.1.15.50.31 (3 cherry picked commits)
                  \
                   * - *   <-- Tag.1.15.50.32 (2 cherry picked commits)
```

and you want to find all commits reachable from `Tag.1.15.50.32`, excluding all commits reachable from `Tag.1.15.50.31`, which would then be just the two commits marked `*` here?

The command [`git rev-list`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-rev-list) lists revisions that meet some criteria, and [`gitrevisions`](http://git-scm.com/docs/revisions) has syntax to generate revision-sets including precisely the kind you're looking for.  Namely, `B` selects revisions reachable from `B`, and `^A` excludes revisions reachable from `A`, so `B ^A` produces such a list; and the special short-hand syntax `A..B` means `B ^A`.

Thus:

```
git rev-list Tag.1.15.50.31..Tag.1.15.50.32
```

should list just the revisions that were created by the `git cherry-pick` actions.